# How to reduce root mean square error for multivariable linear regression

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I am using Linear Regression from scikit learn to predict target value for this model. But Root mean square error is 765. How can i reduce root mean square error for this model?
[image]

```
clf=LinearRegression().fit(X_train,y_train)
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, clf.predict(X_test))
print("MSE: %.4f" % mse)
rmse=np.sqrt(mse)
print("RMSE: %.4f" % rmse)
```

Comment: can you post some code also

Comment: Sure. i have updated my post

Comment: One possibility is to ensure that the fitted equation contains an offset term, that is, not only "y = a*x" but "y = a*x + b". It should be easy to check just to verify, and if there is no offset term in the fitted equation then adding an offset term might help.

Comment: @JamesPhillips please do not speculate irresponsibly: [scikit-learn LR](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn-linear-model-linearregression) includes a `fit_intercept` argument, with default value `True`...

Comment: That is certainly an interesting comment. I will carefully consider it in its proper professional context.